How to force a lambda function to return an object rather than the None value of the last method on the object?
Sometimes I cannot use a lambda function on an object because the last method applied to the object returns None. What is the trick to be able to return the object itself instead of the method returned value?
Example, I want to get the updated copy of the dictionary instead of None:
dict_update = lambda d, upd: d.copy().update(upd)

d = dict(lw=3, ls='-')
upd = dict(c='C0', lw=4)
d1 = dict_update(d, upd)
for v in [d, upd, d1]: print(v)


{'lw': 3, 'ls': '-'}
{'c': 'C0', 'lw': 4}
None


The trick is to not use lambda.

This question is similar to: How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression in Python?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The question is valid, even if the example use of the lambda expression is an anti-pattern.

@IgnatiusReilly They said that's an Example. Of the more general thing they want.

You could use dict unpacking and packing:
dict_update = lambda d, upd: {**d, **upd}


Or dict_update = dict.__or__.

@mins How does this answer anything other than your example?
